# testing directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I've created directive which create link for images if the src of the image wasn't available as following:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('defaultImage', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var url = 'http://placehold.it/' + element.attr('default-image');
      element.bind('error', function() {
        element.addClass('default-image');
        element.attr('src', url);
      })
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <img ng-src="/logo.jpg" default-image="103x89" alt="Logo!" />

</div>
```

It works as expected, but what I want is to make a test unit for this directive, I tried many ways but I couldn't manage to make the test working correctly, the test code as follow:

```js
'use strict';

describe('Directive: defaultImage', function () {

  var element, compile, scope;

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope;
    compile = $compile;
  }));

  function compileImage(markup, scope){
    var el = compile(markup)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    return el;
  }

  it('should make image with default image src link', inject(function () {
    var image = compileImage('<img ng-src="/logo.jpg" default-image="200x48" alt="Default Image!" class="img"/>', scope);
    expect(image.attr('src')).toEqual('http://placehold.it/200x48');
  }));
});
```

Thanx for any advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding to the error event in your directive

```
   element.bind('error', function() {
        element.addClass('default-image');
        element.attr('src', url);
   })
```

The above piece of code however never gets triggered in your test, hence it will always fail. Just triggering an error manually in your test will fix the problem.

```
it('should make image with default image src link', inject(function() {
    var image = compileImage('<img ng-src="/logo.jpg" default-image="200x48" alt="Default Image!" class="img"/>', scope);
    image.error(); // Trigger the error manually
    expect(image.attr('src')).toEqual('http://placehold.it/200x48');
}));
```

You can debug your karma tests from any browser

- Open a browser and navigate to `http://localhost:9876/debug.html` (default karma configuration, may vary)
- Start your developer tools and place breakpoints in the directive and the directive test
- Refresh
- Breakpoints will be hit

With this approach you can narrow down any problems in your tests more easily.

Cheers

Comment: thanx man that fixed it, and now I have the directive and the unit test working perfectly